# Rails app complaining can't connect to memcached but I'm pretty sure it's running

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, memcached

All was well, then I rebooted the server.

Right now:

```
$ ps aux | grep memcache
1000     27168  0.0  0.0 121972  1056 pts/0    Sl   15:18   0:00 memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u nobody -l 127.0.0.1
1000     27816  0.0  0.0   7628   956 pts/0    S+   15:36   0:00 grep memcache
```

meanwhile the rails app's log is getting tons of this:

```
MemCacheError (No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:55 -0600 2011)): No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:55 -0600 2011)
MemCacheError (No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:55 -0600 2011)): No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:55 -0600 2011)
MemCacheError (No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:55 -0600 2011)): No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:55 -0600 2011)
MemCacheError (No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:55 -0600 2011)): No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:55 -0600 2011)
MemCacheError (No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:56 -0600 2011)): No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:56 -0600 2011)
MemCacheError (No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:56 -0600 2011)): No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:56 -0600 2011)
MemCacheError (No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:56 -0600 2011)): No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:56 -0600 2011)
MemCacheError (No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:56 -0600 2011)): No connection to server (localhost:11211 DEAD (Timeout::Error: execution expired), will retry at Tue Feb 15 15:35:56 -0600 2011)
```

Being that I'm more of a developer than a server guy, and being that we don't really *have* a "server guy," and this being in production... where do I start with this?

Answer (score 3):

```
netstat -tupln | grep -i memcache
```

This will tell you if your memcache instance is listening and on what
port. I'd check in /etc/hosts that localhost is defined. It should be
by default but if someone has gone DD happy in Vi you can get real
problems. Your PS output shows memcache starting with -l 127.0.0.1 but your script is connecting to 'localhost' - This be by definition is the same thing, but, it's arbitrary in the fact you can delete the localhost line, or re-alias to the IP that's up on eth0.

memcache is a plain-text protcol, so try telnetting to the port

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
```

you should get the same response from

```
telnet localhost 11211
```

Comment: Those are helpful tips.  In my case it ended up being that the loopback device wasn't working for some reason. Weird. After ifdown and then ifup it things were back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue and it was resolved once we swapped memcache client

https://github.com/mperham/dalli

(wasn't too much work to change)